# Angulas 1 & Angular 2 - Hide api calls...possible?

Tags: angularjs, angular, angularjs-service, angular2-services

I think I know the answer, but I'd like more opinions.

Imagine a scenario...

You create a new website using angular 1 or 2 where basically your front end application consumes services from a server that's send you results in json - The trivial scenario.

Then a competitor decide to create one web site to compete with yours. It's pretty easy to open Developers Tools on the browser and check the address of the rest server including api parameters. So, the competitor decides to create a migration tool to make easy for people to abandon your web site and adopt the competitor web site.

CORS cannot protect you because it's much more a browser feature - also you can use JSONp to consume api of different domains.

So, the question: **Is there any solution for a scenario like this ?**

Comment: This isn't Angular related at all. It's also mostly opiononated which is discouraged on StackOverflow. You also don't state what it should depend on when one should be able to access your service and when not. If you want a solution that automatically blocks all bad guys I can ensure you there is none yet ;-)

Comment: I don't  agree...maybe there is some technical solution for this. If Angular is not capable , it's does no means that's not related.

Comment: I don't think that a competitor which use your backend solution is a real competitor for you. Why someone should do that?

Comment: If you own your back end API, then add **Authentication**. Forget browser, if you have an open API, then it's trivial to call it without a browser unless you protect it one way or the other.

Comment: @MarcoS.Junior Your question is not even browser related. That as server service topic. If you have a solution from this perspective then you can ask how to make Angular work with that.

Comment: Easy, Simon...have you decided to replace your current music streaming provider ? Need to recreate all your playlists on the new service ?? Ouch !!! For many people it could be more easy to stay in a bad service indeed - Unless if it's possible to migrate so easy.

Comment: Again, Gunter: Nope, it's not. What if A1 or A2 have some kind of feature for that ? My opinion: The question left you angry because it could be a very good arg to not use Angular. Sorry to hurt your feelings. Server service ?? Come on ! LOL...If you don't know the answer...you are free to leave the topic.

Comment: If it is your API, you are free to deny CORS/JSONP/whatever. If it is third-party API, you are free to proxy it through your server and deny CORS/JSONP/whatever. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

You can obfuscate your API, but you can't hide the calls that are made to it.

There's a single good reason for this : the browser of the final user needs to know what requests to make, and make them.
Even if you found some way to hide the requests made from the Developper Tools, someone could still retrieve them by listening for them on the network.

However as I said, you can still obfuscate your API so that trying to replicate it would require non-trivial work. That way, an understandable request like

```
GET /user/id1234/profile?history=true
```

could become the less talkative

```
GET /1/id1234/p?x=1
```

Comment: Got your point, Aaron...means : let the things not so easy. Good !!

Comment: Security through obscurity doesn't work for APIs. Maintaining a gimp API that can be reverse-engineered in a day or two is a shot in the foot, it obviously causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :( :(

Comment: @estus While you're quite possibly right that it isn't worth the pain, I wouldn't assimilate this situation with the phrase "security through obscurity" since nobody here is claiming to be more secure by obfuscating code. The code obfuscation here is its own goal, rather than a way to hide unsecure algorithms.